# The HomeController default on laravel doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new on laravel, and I am making some test and following a tutorial. The matter is that I don´t know what I did two days ago that I got any defaults controllers (maybe only one... I don´t remember, for example: HomeController). I removed the project and create a new one... but now these defaults controllers don´t exit. And my routes.php on app/http folder is like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

ONLY THIS!!!

I remember that the routes.php file of the first laravel test project had something like: get("home")... or get("login"), etc...

Do I need to install them via artisan or something?

Comment: Not sure which tutorial you were using but Laravel only comes with the AuthControllers by default. Everything else you either pull in, or generate yourself using the php artisan commands.  If you check out my profile there are some tutorials there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe authentication? It will create some views and routes.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart

The command php artisan make:auth if you are using 5.2.*

Answer (score 2):

When installing Laravel, i. e. with this command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`, there is no `app/Http/Controller/HomeController.php` generated.

You *only* get one route in your `routes.php`. That's it!

What you could do, of course, is:

- Create a class `HomeController.php` in `app/Htpp/Controllers` - use `php artisan make:controller HomeController`
- Change the route in your `routes.php` to utilize the new `HomeController`

  - `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')`;

Another thing you may did in the past was running `php artisan make:auth` to initialize basic controller ands views to get a scaffold for logins/registers of users.

Comment: Thanks @codedge... but what I did two days ago was something automatic. I use laravel installer, so I do: laravel new project and after php artisan make:auth on the project´s folder.So your solution is not 100% correct. I knew that the php artisan make:controller name serves to make new controllers... but the solution I was searching supplies too the views.

Answer (score 1):

no you don't if you want to create a controller just t`php artisan make:controller HomeController` and a controller will be created for you :)

Comment: Thanks @IbrahimFleifel... but what I did two days ago was something automatic. I use laravel installer, so I do: laravel new project and after php artisan make:auth on the project´s folder. So your solution is not 100% correct. I knew that the php artisan make:controller name serves to make new controllers... but the solution I was searching supplies too the views.